# How to get Linux autocompletion with numbered menu?

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete

I've been trying to find this for a couple of days now and while I am aware that I can write a bash function to get it the way I want, I am sure that this option comes out of the box.

I have recently upgraded to RHEL 7.11 and in previous RHEL versions when using double tab it would display a numbered menu when I had ambiguous options.

Consider this, I have a directory with the following files:

```
abc  abcd  abcde  abcdef  abcdefg  abcdefgh  abcdefghi
```

So when I type:

```
cat abc [tab][tab]
```

And there were multiple matches, I would get:

```
1) abc
2) abcd
3) abcde
4) abcdef
5) abcdefg
6) abcdefgh
7) abcdefghi
```

Subsequently I could type **'7'** and **[tab]** and it would concatenate the file at the option **7)**.

This is super useful when there are a lot of similar options with many files starting with the same characters (as is the case on my server where file names are preceded with system names for clarity).

Any ideas?

Comment: Well bash autocomplete functionality is rudimentary. Other shells have it more powerful like zsh which have interactive autocompletion. Maybe try something else than bash.

Comment: Thanks Karol. I also have ksh installed so that could be a possibility. But then the question remains, how can I re-produce it on my new RHEL version?

Comment: It might be a very late suggestion, in general what you could do is try to study how that functionality is implemented in the prior Linux version. For example, since it is not mentioned here what version it is, try to install it on a virtual machine, or on some other PC that is not needed. It could be some configuration file, but I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your input Krassi, it was an old 5.7 version of RHEL but it’s end of life as of now. I’ll have to deal with laborious (everything is relative..) menu listing until further notice (-:

Comment: You could use `fish` which has built-in auto-suggestion/auto-completion based on your command history. Alternatively `zsh` has a [fish like autocompletion plugin](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions). Doesn't have the list of options though... I personally use and recommend `zsh` on account of how similar it is to `bash` (`fish` is a bit different a requires some time to get used to).

Comment: If interested: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/tree/master/Completion

Comment: If you want to keep using bash instead of fish or zsh, a good solution would be using [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)... so you can choose files / directories from a list based on simple patterns, I personally use some key bindings to make my life easier... like control-X + F will do a quick search starting from current dir...  more details [at my dotfiles](https://github.com/fsilveir/.dotfiles)

Comment: Open a Case at Red Hat if it worked with versions <7.11.

Comment: Btw. Current versions are 7.7 and 8.1.

Comment: I found this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447638/27653 Not exactly what you ask for, but nice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend https://github.com/junegunn/fzf, I started to replace all my in-shell menu choices with this GREAT tool.

It has bash support, batteries included.